# Is there an AR SDK in unity for changing of Image Targets during runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there any ar sdk that allow user to change image target on runtime? i tried it on vuforia but they don't have this kind of feature yet.any suggestions? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vuforia has cloud image targets [link](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Cloud-Recognition-Guide)

ARCore can do what you want [link2](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images/guide)

Comment: can i also upload image target on runtime sir using one of these? thank you for you respond by the way.

Comment: yes, you can. But i advice you to use ARCore, because cloud recognition is unstable and hard to use properly. Link2 is example how to add image target in runtime

Comment: Thank you sir.  Does ArCore also support storing image target on a database like mysql?

Comment: sure read this https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c/group/augmented-image-database#group__augmented__image__database_1ga02ade9d0bf7f6ca7c3cbcad7570cd037

Comment: if i answered your question, mark it resolved pls :)